# resolving @Value fails when invoked from external class - spring java

Tags: java, spring

In the property file (config.properties) I defined several properties:

```
my.property.first=xyz
my.property.second=12
```

I created a class to read these properties:

```
package my.package.first;
............

@Configuration
public Class MyProperties {

    @Value("${my.property.first}") private String propertyFirst;

    @Value ("${my.property.second}") private String propertySecond;

    public String getPropertyFirst() {
        return propertyFirst;
    }

    public int getPropertySecond() {
        return propertySecond
    }

    @Bean 
    public MyProperties getInstance() {
        return this;
    } 
}
```

Now I want to use these properties in a class placed in some other package:

```
package my.otherpackage.third;

import my.property.package.first.MyProperties;
.............................
public class GetMyProperties{

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context  = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyProperties.class);

    MyProperties myProperties =context.getBean("getInstance",MyProperties.class);

    //This returns ${my.property.first}
    String propertyFirst = myProperties.getPropertyFirst();

    // This returns ${my.property.second}
    int propertySecond = context.getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue(("${my.property.first}"));
}
```

I try to solve this by using only Annotations.

I use Spring 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MyProperties isn't really a @Configuration class, it is a bean. Give it the annotation @Component and move the @Bean declaration to another @Configuration class. It doesn't matter where the bean is defined for spring (as long as it is in a configuration class), it'll pick it up if you have the @ComponentScan or @SpringBootApplication somewhere in your app, which I'm pretty sure you do. your MyProperties class you make @Component

You'll want:

```
@Component
public class MyProperties {
    @Value("${my.property.first}") private String propertyFirst;

    @Value ("${my.property.second}") private String propertySecond;

    public String getPropertyFirst() {
        return propertyFirst;
    }

    public void setPropertyFirst(String propertyFirst){
        this.propertyFirst = propertyFirst;
    }

    public int getPropertySecond() {
        return propertySecond
    }

    public void setPropertySecond(String propertySecond){
        this.propertySecond= propertySecond;
    }
}



@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean 
    public MyProperties getInstance() {
        return new MyProperties();
    } 
}



package my.otherpackage.third;

import my.property.package.first.MyProperties;
.....
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my"})
public class GetMyProperties{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context  = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(GetMyProperties.class);

        MyProperties myProperties =context.getBean("getInstance",MyProperties.class);

        //This returns the value of ${my.property.first}
        String propertyFirst = myProperties.getPropertyFirst();

        // This returns the value of ${my.property.second}
        int propertySecond = myProperties.getPropertySecond();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the bean getInstance() just to get myProperties instance. How can I access properties in the class GetMyProperties if I remove this bean?

Comment: Define the bean at another place, your bean cannot be configuration and a bean at the same time. It doesn't matter where the bean is defined for spring (as long as it is in a configuration class), it'll pick it up if you have the \@ComponentScan or \@SpringBootApplication somewhere in your app, which I'm pretty sure you do.

Comment: I meant is there a way to access These properties without using this bean at all?

Comment: You can access these properties in *every* bean, thus every class with the annotation .@Component, .@Service, .@Repository or .@Controller, by using the .@Value annotation in the way you are doing.

Comment: I added both annotations (@Component and @Configure) to MyProperties class - it did not work.

Comment: @uztrew, please check other comments or code example.

Comment: context.getMessage(resolvable, locale) requires two arguments

Comment: Don't do that part, I just tested it and it's not working, the code example I provided works 100%. But if you want to try, the current Locale you get by Locale.getDefault()

Comment: OK Thanks for answer

Comment: No problem, could you please accept it then? I've put some time and effort into this question...

Comment: I'll have to check it first and if it works I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Sounds only fair, note that I added the @EnableAutoConfiguration and .@ComponentScan annotations and tweaked your main method to make it fully functional.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without spring boot, I mean somehow to skip @EnableAutoConfiguration ?